# Is it possible to activate the watchdog on any Linux machine?

Tags: linux-kernel, raspbian, watchdog

On an [Orange Pi Zero](http://www.orangepi.org/orangepizero/) running a Raspbian server, it's possible to use the watchdog very easily just by running the command `echo 1 > /dev/watchdog` as root. The idea is that the system will certainly reboot after some time that this command is executed, so I need to keep repeating this command in a regular interval of time to keep the system on. We can implement a watchdog using `cron` as root and making it execute the following script on boot:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ true ]; do
    echo 1 > /dev/watchdog
    sleep 5
done
```

This script works fine on the Orange Pi Zero... However, on my desktop computer running Ubuntu 18.04 the command `echo 1 > /dev/watchdog` doesn't work at all. **Is it possible to activate the watchdog on any device running Linux?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two types of watchdog; hardware and software.  On the Orange Pi the SOC chip provides a hardware watchdog.  If initialised then it needs to be pinged every so often, otherwise it performs a board reset.

However not many desktops have hardware watchdogs, so the kernel provides a software version.  Now the kernel will try and keep track, and force a reboot.  This isn't as good as a hardware watchdog because if the kernel, itself, breaks then nothing will trigger the reset.  But it works.

The software watchdog can be initialised by loading the `softdog` module

```
% modprobe softdog
% dmesg | tail -1
[  120.573945] softdog: Software Watchdog Timer: 0.08 initialized. soft_noboot=0 soft_margin=60 sec soft_panic=0 (nowayout=0)
```

We can see this has a 60 second timeout by default.

If I then do

```
% echo > /dev/watchdog
% dmesg | tail -1
[  154.514976] watchdog: watchdog0: watchdog did not stop!
```

We can see the watchdog hadn't timed out.

I then leave the machine idle for a minute and on the console I see

```
[  214.624112] softdog: Initiating system reboot
```

and the OS reboots.

Comment: Many desktops, laptops and servers include hardware watchdogs, often in their Super-I/O chips, or in their PCH; see the various “wdt” modules in the kernel.

Comment: @StephenHarris Can I assume that when the command `echo > /dev/watchdog` doesn't work at first it's because there's no hardware watchdog for that device? Or there's still the possibility that I need to activate the hardware watchdog before using it?

Comment: @StephenKitt It's possible all my machines are too old... I haven't done a hardware refresh in over a decade!

Comment: If `/dev/watchdog` doesn't exist (or isn't a character device) and you know your hardware has a watchdog, then you may need to `modprobe` the relevant hardware driver...  Modern distro's will try to load this automatically, but you may have an edge-case.  None of my machines have a `/dev/watchdog` entry :-(

Comment: “Many”, not “all” ;-). My last two personal PCs (2003, 2013) have supported `iTCO_wdt`, and all my work PCs for the last decade or so have supported one driver or another, but it isn’t loaded automatically; as you mention, in many cases the relevant module needs to be loaded manually, and sometimes the firmware setup has to be configured appropriately too (and sometimes a jumper must be moved on the main board).

Comment: @StephenKitt What do you mean exactly when you say "firmware setup"?

Comment: @Rafael the BIOS or UEFI setup on a PC.

Comment: @StephenKitt, do you know how to check if my PC has hardware watchdog?

Comment: @MichealXIV you can try loading the various watchdog modules, or look at your motherboard’s documentation.

Comment: @StephenKitt: It seems that my PC does not have a hardware watchdog. So I need to try to use softdog as your comment. But it is not useful when kernel is hung. Do you have any idea for this case?

Comment: @MichaelXIV unfortunately that’s the main scenario where you need a hardware watchdog...

Comment: @MichealXIV you could use a USB watchdog device and connect it to the reset pins of your motherboard.

Answer (score 4):

On a modern Linux operating system that uses systemd you can configure systemd to interact with the hardware watchdog on your behalf, rather than doing it yourself or using a separate user-space daemon.

You can do that by setting a (positive) `RuntimeWatchdogSec` value in the 
systemd configuration file, `/etc/systemd/system.conf`.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the hardware. With modern enough Linux kernel and intel CPU you should be able to do following if you run Ubuntu or some other Debian variant:

1. `sudo apt install watchdog`
2. `sudo nano -w /etc/default/watchdog`
   and define correct module, such as `watchdog_module="iTCO_wdt"` (note that the correct driver name depends on your hardware but this should be good enough for intel CPUs manufactured during the last 10 years). When the watchdog service is started, it will load this kernel module which will make `/dev/watchdog` device to appear in the system.
3. `sudo nano -w /etc/watchdog.conf`
   uncomment the line `watchdog-device = /dev/watchdog` or just add that line as extra line to that file. The end result should match this:

   ```
    $ grep -vE '^(#|$)' /etc/watchdog.conf
    watchdog-device = /dev/watchdog
    realtime        = yes
    priority        = 1
   ```
4. `sudo systemctl enable --now watchdog`

All the possible watchdog driver modules can be listed with command

```
ls "/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/watchdog"
```

and if you don't have a clue which one to use, you can try testing those one by one. For example, to test driver `sp5100_tco.ko` simply run `sudo modprobe sp5100_tco` and then run `sudo wd_identify` to tell if your hardware is supported by that driver. If it didn't work, remove the driver with `sudo modprobe -r sp5100_tco` and retry with another. Note that `wd_identify` cannot be used if watchdog process is already connected to the hardware so you cannot use that after enabling the watchdog.

To test the watchdog hardware you can cause artificial failure by simply opening the device and never writing anything to it. For example, before enabling the `watchdog` service in last step, you can simply run `sudo cat /dev/watchdog` and the system will automatically reset in about 60 seconds. This works because the watchdog driver works by starting the watchdog timer when the file is opened and the only way to reset the timer is to write something to the driver device. Closing the file will also stop the timer instead of causing a reboot (unless your kernel has been compiled with non-default flags which cause reset even if nobody is using watchdog device anymore after it has been used at all after boot). When you run `cat` on the driver file, the file will be opened and the `cat` process will stall trying to read the file and hardware reset will be done when the timer expires (which should be 60 seconds by default). It's a good idea to save all work and sync the filesystem before attempting this!

For details about the kernel watchdog driver, see the [official kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/watchdog/watchdog-api.html).

Comment: You can also use `kill -STOP $pid_of_the_watchdog_process` to test if your system correctly reboots if the actual watchdog process ever hangs.

Answer (score 1):

The I/O redirection closes the watchdog file handle after writing the `1`. Depending on how the watchdog device is configured, closing the file handle can also disable the watchdog.

Try

```
exec 3>/dev/watchdog
echo 1 >&3
```

This will keep the watchdog device open in the current shell, so the timer will not be stopped.

Most people run a dedicated watchdog daemon rather than using cron; this daemon runs a list of checks before resetting the timer, so the machine also reboots if tests fail. This could be used to verify that a database service actually processes queries, while regular service monitoring would only verify that the process is running.